# Bootstrap popover fails inside *ngIf in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I am trying to display popover inside container but it does not work,

if I remove the *ngIf it works

where ever there if *ngIf it doesn't render

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="data" >
  <button 
    class="popover" 
    data-trigger="hover" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-content="hello" 
    data-container="body">
  <mat-icon>
   info
  </mat-icon>
 </button>
</div>
```

//ts file

````js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
//... variables 
//... constructor

  ngOnInit() {
      $('.popover').popover({
        boundary: 'viewport',
        placement: 'top',
        container:'body',
        sanitize: true,
        appendToBody: true
      })

  }
}```
````

Comment: whats data here, is it set before calling popover?

Comment: data is an array fetched from API 
and yes it is set before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because the div.container is not rendered by angular by the time when ngOnInit() is called by angular. Instead you can use the AfterViewInit Lifecycle hook as shown below.

Pay attention that the paragraph with the ngIf can't be loaded in the ngOnInit but it can be loaded in the ngAfterViewInit.

Stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-lifecycle-hook

#### component.html

```
<p id="p1">
  Without ngIf
</p>

<p id="p2" *ngIf="data">
  With ngIf
</p>
```

#### component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
    data = {random: 'text'};

    ngOnInit() {
        const withoutNgIf = document.getElementById('p1');
        const withNgIf = document.getElementById('p2');

        console.log('OnInit without ngIf: ', withoutNgIf);
        # Output: HTMLParagraphElement
        console.log('OnInit with ngIf: ', withNgIf);
        # Output: null
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const withNgIf = document.getElementById('p2');  
        console.log('AfterViewInit with ngIf: ', withNgIf);
        # Output: HTMLParagraphElement
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you to understand the problem.

Tip: I would suggest to use the ViewChild decorator to access the DOM instead of jquery if you are using angular. (Example: https://dev.to/danielpdev/how-to-use-viewchild-decorator-in-angular-9-i0)